# who know how to compare two binary image and how to encode a binary image

Tags: image-processing

when we have two binary image,may be they are similar, How can we let computer knows it.
shall we do something such as encoding the binary image to compare, my question is how can I do that.

Comment: Could you please focus your question a little?  What specific do you want to know?   What are you trying to do?

Comment: you can not understand me. I am sorry about your understanding ability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a great place to start [here at a C-Sharp Corner post](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/ShowMessages.aspx?ThreadID=64790).